# PDF doc view emacs doesn't render properly

Tags: pdf, emacs

I just configured my emacs to display PDFs using doc view. But the problem is that the display flickers continuously. It seems that doc view is constantly refreshing the frame leading to an unpleasant display. How do I stop it from doing this?

Also, I haven't done any customization to doc view in my .emacs yet.

I'm using emacs 24.4 on Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Note: This is a repost to the original question [PDF doc view flickers continously](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/13791/pdf-doc-view-flickers-continously) on Emacs StackExchange. But I didn't get any answers so I have reposted it here with better hopes.

Comment: I don't believe that this is technically a "programing question".  The original poster may have better luck bumping the Emacs Beta question by making a slight edit, which would make it pop back up again at the top of the active list.  A few of the gurus involved in Emacs development and other savvy `elisp` writers frequent both forums.